# How often have closed questions been reopened?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Does anyone have any stats on how many closed questions have been reopened?

From my time here it seems that this rarely, if ever, happens. I'm just curious if this impression is accurate. Wouldn't be surprising since most of the closed questions I've seen are from new users or first-time posters who might not feel like coming back if their first attempt didn't yield an answer.

Comment: Yeah, I've definitely seen it happen organically occasionally (and I actually cast an unclose vote on a question fairly recently, within the last two or three weeks)

Comment: Not common, but not really due to a problem with the returning userbase or the way the site is structure (functionally), but rather mostly with new users who are just in-and-out looking for a quick answer. Don't have the stats on it though, you'd have to check by hand. :\

Comment: @stoicfury Ah ok, I thought maybe access to these stats was among your magical mod abilities. Oh well, certainly not curious enough to check by hand.

Comment: We do have stats, just not this specifically. :\

Answer (score 2):

There've been 549 questions closed on Philosophy.SE. Out of these, 67 have been re-opened.

This is actually a fairly respectable ratio - assuming most questions are closed for good reason. Note also that about half of all closed questions have been deleted.